# zsh: no such file or directory error but file exist

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to run a compiler but I'm getting an error saying it can not be found, but it looks to exist and the path is good. I even tried a different shell incase zsh was mis-configured, but got the same error. Lost at what to do, any suggestions?

```
6909077c228a% ls -l toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2287465 Sep 11 13:19 toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
6909077c228a% ./toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
zsh: no such file or directory: ./toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
#switch to bash
6909077c228a:~$ ./toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc
bash: ./toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

Edit:
Update showing suggestion, don't see any odd character inserted.

```
6909077c228a% ls -l toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc | od -xcb
0000000    722d    7877    2d72    7278    782d    3220    7220    6f6f
      -   r   w   x   r   -   x   r   -   x       2       r   o   o
    055 162 167 170 162 055 170 162 055 170 040 062 040 162 157 157
0000020    2074    6f72    746f    3220    3832    3437    3536    5320
      t       r   o   o   t       2   2   8   7   4   6   5       S
    164 040 162 157 157 164 040 062 062 070 067 064 066 065 040 123
0000040    7065    3120    2031    3331    313a    2039    6f74    6c6f
      e   p       1   1       1   3   :   1   9       t   o   o   l
    145 160 040 061 061 040 061 063 072 061 071 040 164 157 157 154
0000060    6863    6961    2f6e    6962    2f6e    7261    766d    6c37
      c   h   a   i   n   /   b   i   n   /   a   r   m   v   7   l
    143 150 141 151 156 057 142 151 156 057 141 162 155 166 067 154
0000100    742d    6d69    7365    7379    6c2d    6e69    7875    672d
      -   t   i   m   e   s   y   s   -   l   i   n   u   x   -   g
    055 164 151 155 145 163 171 163 055 154 151 156 165 170 055 147
0000120    756e    6165    6962    672d    6363    000a
      n   u   e   a   b   i   -   g   c   c  \n
    156 165 145 141 142 151 055 147 143 143 012
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you typed in your initial `ls -l` line, there *may* be funny characters in the file name. If you use auto completion, it may have put those funny characters in *for* you so, if you subsequently attempt to type in the file name *without* auto completion, that could result in a file not found situation.

The first thing you should do is to check the filename completely, with something like:

```
ls -l toolchain/bin/armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc | od -xcb
```

and check the output to ensure there's no funny characters in the name.

---

If the file does exist in that for (no funny characters), one other possibility is that you're trying to run a 32-bit ELF program on a system that's not correctly set up to run them (i.e., a 64-bit system without the libraries and support infrastructure for 32-bit).

That results in an unhelpful error message since it really should be complaining about not being able to find the *loader* for your 32-bit executable, rather than the executable itself.

If this is the case, you will need to identify those missing items and install them.